# POI evaluate formula cell IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-poi

Without FormulaEvaluator I can pass the formula to excel, but while retrieving the value from the formula cell gives me the null value (by using `cell.getRawValue()` ) .

So I tried FormulaEvaluator API to evaluate formula.

Here I used VLOOKUP formula in setFormula() method of XSSFCell, FormulaEvaluator evaluate(formulaCell) method throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

Please help to set VLOOKUP formula and get the value after execution of formula.

FYI, 
I am using poi-3.9-20121203.jar

Below is my code snippet and corresponding exception,

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Excel_Vlookup\\temp1.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
XSSFCell formulaCell = null;
CellValue cellValue = null;

int count = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
formulaCell = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(7);
formulaCell.setCellFormula("VLOOKUP(B"+(i+1)+",'D:\\Excel_Vlookup\\[temp2.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,3,0)");
cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(formulaCell);
}
file.close();
```

Got exception as below,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sheetIndex: -1.
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.<init>(SheetRefEvaluator.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:97)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.getArea3DEval(OperationEvaluationContext.java:259)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:576)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:458)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:279)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:221)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:257)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:116)
at com.cgi.MyExcelFormula.writeFormula(MyExcelFormula.java:31)
at com.cgi.MyExcelFormula.main(MyExcelFormula.java:52)
```

Comment: In first look it seems that it is a reference error....